# what should i write to redirect the page from Controller in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

here is my Controller

```
<?php 
class First_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){

        $this->load->view('firstpage');
    }

    public function validate_credentials()
    {
        $data[] =array(

            $username=$this->input->post('username'),
            $password=$this->input->post('password')
            );
        $this->load->model('First_Model');
        $result=$this->First_Model->validate($data);

        if($result==true)
        {
            //redirect('welcome');//Error Page is not found
            echo "found";
        }
        else{

            echo "not found";
        }
    }

}
?>

and here is the second controller 



   <?php 
    class Welcome_Controller extends CI_Controller{
        public function index(){

            $this->load->model('First_Model');
            $data['results']=$this->First_Model->display();

            $this->load->view('welcome',$data);
    }       }   
    ?>
```

if i write indirect to my page it show the error page is not found , if i give it a controller same error , and if i gave page redirect('welcome'); show error . i dont know what to do , could anyone guide me . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Follow These Steps:

1. Did you load **url helper** ?

   if not then first load the url helper

   `$this->load->helper('url');`

   in your **function** or **constructer**.

   if you want to use it in whole application then load it in **autoload.php** file
2. In your **config.php** file give your **site url**

   `$config['base_url']='your site url';`
3. in **redirect** function give axact path of file name use **url helper function**

   `redirect(base_url().'welcome');`

   if you want to redirect on another controller's function pass it like

   `redirect('Welcome_Controller');`

   if the function is index no need to define it, to redirect on another function

   `redirect('Welcome_controller/anotherFunction');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/welcome');` if you use htaccess and do not need index.php then make it like `redirect(base_url() . 'welcome');`

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect('Welcome_Controller');
```

Thats enough. please check weather your controller name is'Welcome_Controller'

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
redirect(base_url('cms/lists')); 

//for edit or updating the form - you can pass ID like this

$ID=$this->uri->segment(3);
redirect(base_url("cms/edit/".$ID));
```